# How to figure out in what pom a dependency from effective pom is defined in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a big project that has parent `pom`, this one has another parent; in the project's `pom` file another project with `bom` file is included as a dependency, etc.

I click on `pom` and generate `effective pom`. Inside I see a dependency, for example this one

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <version>1.18.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there an easy way in IntelliJ to find the `pom` where this dependency is defined?

Answer (score 0):

In Ultimate version it's possible to generate a diagram for all maven dependencies:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#maven_dependency_diagram

Or you can execute `mvn dependency:tree` to build full dependency tree.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html
https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-display-project-dependency/

Comment: Thanks, I tried but at the diagram it doesn't show the dependencies of parent pom dependencies. `mvn dependency:tree` didn't help neither.

Comment: Is it possible to execute `mvn dependency:tree` or create diagram not from child pom, but from parent? (If parent is in your projrct)
Or, maybe, what if you include parent pom as dependency, not as parent and make diagram/tree from child pom?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but there are dependencies that have their parent pom files. The idea of the question was to write some command or click some button and see where in such complex structure a dependency is included.
What I did was the search for a line `1.18.10` in all files that I had in my project and as far as I remember also in my local maven repository. Then I needed to look one by one. This worked but I'm sure that it was not the best way to solve the problem.